# Validating models in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Validation Attribute ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483027/custom-validation-attribute-asp-net-mvc)

I set up an Attribute.cs file and a Models.cs file.

In the Models.cs, I have:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[Display(Name = "DOB")]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[Display(Name = "Age")]
[Range(7,12,ErrorMessage = "Age must be between 7-12")]
[DOB()]
public string Age { get; set; }
```

I created a custom validation (`DOB` function) in the Attribute.cs file.

In that function, how do I check the `DOB` field and automatically assign the age value? I'm not sure how to even grab the DOB value.

I have the following in my attribute.cs, and it's hitting this function just fine when I put a breakpoint in there:

```
namespace SF.Validation
{
    public class DOBAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public DOBAttribute(string dob)
        {
            //not sure how to grab DOB value?? Need to do it here.
            //this just validates user input, but need to change to automatically 
            //assign the age based on DOB
            DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
            int age = now.Year - DOB.Year; //DOB.Year isn't grabbing anything
            DateTime birthday = new DateTime(DOB.Year, DOB.Month, DOB.Day);

            if (now < birthday.AddYears(age)) age--;

            if (age < 7 || age > 12)
            {
                IsValid(false);
            }
            else
            {
                IsValid(true);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can we see the code for the `DOB` attribute please?

Comment: How did you implement your DOB attribute?

Comment: FYI, you don't need a Display attribute if your Display name is the same as the property name.

Comment: I posted the code as an answer below so it's easier to read.

Comment: jrummell, the IsValid() part isn't the issue I'm having. The problem is that the code isn't recognizing DOB.Year. I'm not sure how to do that part?